# Blender closes with no error message 1-2 minutes after launching

Tags: error

I don't remember when this started but now its gotten to the point where Blender will close 30 seconds to 3 minutes after launching it. It requires no input from me, I could be alt-tabbed doing something else and it will close by itself. There's no error message, no spike in my task manager, nothing. I reinstalled it twice (2.79) and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Try opening a command prompt and running blender.exe from there. Then any error messages generated will be preserved when blender crashes. For arguments sake try opening blender and immediately choosing File -> Load Factory Settings and then leaving it alone to rule out any add-ons or customisations.